# Issue with the font character from the value extracted through jquery ajax method

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

I am using jquery ajax to display some values inside the label when some value is selected from select box. but the value that i want to display in label is some different font and I think that is why the value is displayed with some question mark characters with black quad box as background [#nb-am-h��#w] .  How to avoid this:

```
//Javascript code
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("document").ready(function(){
        var id=$(this).val();
        //alert(id);

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax.php",
            data: {id:id},
            cache: false,
            success: function(html){
                //alert(html);
                $("#malid").show();
                /*$('#malid').css("font-family", "malfont");*/
                $("#malid").html(html);
            } 
        });
    );
```

HTML code

```
<div>
  <label>Book</label>
  <select id="bookname">
  <?php 
      for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++)
      {
      ?>
           <option  value="<?php echo $bookid[$i];?>"><?php echo    $book_name[$i];?> </option>
      <?php
      } 
  ?>
  </select>
  <label id="malid" style="display:none;font-family: 'malfont';"></label>
 </div>

//Php code inside ajax.php
if(isset($_POST['id']))
{
    $id=$_POST['id'];

    $book_results = $mysqli->query("SELECT book FROM booktable where book_id='$id'");
    $row = $book_results->fetch_assoc();
    $book = $row['book'];
    echo $book;  
}
```

Comment: Your situation is a bit vague with the "some values" and "some different font", and it sounds like the solution is, simply make sure that everything uses the same font. So... can you create a concrete example where things go wrong that we can look at?

Comment: On re-reading, it sounds like the HTML you're fetching contains its own font styling, thus overriding the style attribute in `#malid`, is that it?

Comment: No It is not over-riding..   I feel something is wrong with charset or content type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a solution for my issue. I just included the below line in my Ajax page and it is working fine now.

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-15');
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you check out (using the networks tab or a proxy) what the response is from the AJAX call? Its probably bad encoding in your database / connection.

Also, please note that this AJAX endpoint is vulnerable for SQL Injection (You're not escaping the users' input **$_POST['id']**.

For more information, check out: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection#Technical_implementations